# Questiion with Boost.Asio HTTP Server 1 example:

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Here is part of boost's official http server example:

connection_manager::stop_all method in [connection_manager.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server/connection_manager.cpp)

```
void connection_manager::stop_all()
{
  std::for_each(connections_.begin(), connections_.end(),
      boost::bind(&connection::stop, _1));
  connections_.clear();
}
```

connection::stop method in [connection.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server/connection.cpp)

```
void connection::stop()
{
  socket_.close();
}
```

---

`connection_manager::stop_all` method is 
calling each `connection::stop` method from connection object list and destroying all connection objects.

`connection::stop` method is closing socket, and `socket::close()` method will invoke `connection::handle_read` or `connection::handle_write` handler with an operation_aborted error.

Right?

Then, what if the situation "invoking handler after connection objects already destroyed" ??

I think this situation can cause some unexpected error... isn't it? (and how to deal with this situation?)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what your problem is, but the code you posted does not exhibit the concern you are querying about (as to my understanding). It is your responsibility as the developer to keep the objects you use in scope, and the above code does just that.

It might be explanatory to look at the c++11 version of the above code which is equivalent of the above, just more expressive

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/http/server/connection_manager.cpp

Comment: Yeah. closed != destroyed (closed is a _state_ of the socket, destroyed is _state_ of the C++ object)